2 window cavities on single brick wall
Our contractor messed up and cut the window cavity off centre. His solution was install another window so it didn't look stupid. This is a single brick wall.
Is this structurally safe?
Lintel above windows. They are only half the depth of the brick though. He's coming back to fill mortar and install 2nd window.



Depends on what was done with the lintel of the second window. It it's supported properly it's safe; if he just cut out bricks it probably isn't.

I'm assuming the dark lines in the mortar are steel lintels inserted?

From what I see of the "lintels" as mentioned. I don't see any. I see a cut in the brick on the outside, and not steel lintel placed in the kerf on the inside.
Ideally there shold be a 4" X 4" or maybe a 3" X 4" steel lintel set from the inside, pointed up with masonry cement.
That said, there are structural qualities with the install that I can comment on, but since I am not a structural engineer, I can only speak of my experiences and what I have heard.
Brick or masonry have a rule it can follow called the pyramid effect. It is the imaginary triangle above the opening, for example in your case, it may follow the stair stepping of the brick joints from either side until they meet in the middle to form a peak, roughly speaking of a triangle. Doing that, there are a number of courses of brick that still run continuous over this "triangle" to maintain structure. The lintel in this case would really only be needed to keep the brick that are laid within the triangle to keep from cracking and falling out. I see 3 brick in each opening, that would be supported by th added lintel. The corbelling of the brick above those 3 brick would keep the others from falling.
Again, I am not an engineer, I am making an observation.
